# Filling a shape procedurally with more than one color

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm making an app with node,js,etc. I'd like to fill custom shapes I can create either via data points or another format with different, layered colors. For example, I have a triangle. I want to fill the bottom 1/3 with red, the middle 1/3 with blue, and the top 1/3 with green. How would I go about this?

I'm looking at Paper.js and the basic canvas, but they seem to only have single color fills.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am aware of that an answer has been accepted, but I wanted to present a very simple approach for future readers. Which, as a bonus, automatically calculates the height of each part and is fast, using a **linear gradient** -

## Result will be

[image: snap]

## Code and demo

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150);

grad.addColorStop(0, "red");     // start of red
grad.addColorStop(1/3, "red");   // end of red at 1/3

grad.addColorStop(1/3, "gold");  // start of gold at 1/3
grad.addColorStop(2/3, "gold");  // end of gold at 2/3

grad.addColorStop(2/3, "blue");  // start of blue at 2/3
grad.addColorStop(1, "blue");    // end of blue at 3/3

// Fill a triangle:
ctx.moveTo(75, 0); ctx.lineTo(150, 150); ctx.lineTo(0, 150);
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

## Animated version using compositing technique

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150),
    step = grad.addColorStop.bind(grad), // function reference to simplify
    dlt = -3, y = 150;

step(0, "red");     // start of red
step(1/3, "red");   // end of red at 1/3
step(1/3, "gold");  // start of gold at 1/3
step(2/3, "gold");  // end of gold at 2/3
step(2/3, "blue");  // start of blue at 2/3
step(1, "blue");    // end of blue at 3/3

// store a triangle path - we'll reuse this for the demo loop
ctx.moveTo(75, 0); ctx.lineTo(150, 150); ctx.lineTo(0, 150);

(function loop() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";  // will clear canvas with next draw

  // Fill the previously defined triangle path with any color:
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";  // fill some solid color for performance
  ctx.fill();
  
  // draw a rectangle to clip the top using the following comp mode:
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.fillRect(0, y, 150, 150 - y);

  // now that we have the shape we want, just replace it with the gradient:
  // to do that we use a new comp. mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
  
  y += dlt; if (y <= 0 || y >= 150) dlt = -dlt;  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

## Cached gradient image for animation (recommended)

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    tcanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),    // to cache triangle
    tctx = tcanvas.getContext("2d"),
    grad = tctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150),
    step = grad.addColorStop.bind(grad), // function reference to simplify
    dlt = -3, y = 150;

step(0, "red");     // start of red
step(1/3, "red");   // end of red at 1/3
step(1/3, "gold");  // start of gold at 1/3
step(2/3, "gold");  // end of gold at 2/3
step(2/3, "blue");  // start of blue at 2/3
step(1, "blue");    // end of blue at 3/3

// draw triangle to off-screen canvas once.
tctx.moveTo(75, 0); tctx.lineTo(150, 150); tctx.lineTo(0, 150);
tctx.fillStyle = grad; tctx.fill();

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);

  // draw clipped version of the cached triangle image
  if (150-y) ctx.drawImage(tcanvas, 0, y, 150, 150 - y, 0, y, 150, 150 - y);

  y += dlt; if (y <= 0 || y >= 150) dlt = -dlt;  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

You can change direction using the gradient *line*, which dictates the angle of the gradient.

```
// vertical 
ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 150); // x1, y1, x2, y2

// hortizontal
ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 150, 0); // x1, y1, x2, y2

// 45° degrees
ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 150, 150); // x1, y1, x2, y2
```

etc.

Comment: This approach is way better, shorter and no danger for ghostly remains of other drawn pixels

Comment: I like this as well, I'll give both a shot. Would you be able to use animate() on this to make it fill up from the bottom?

Comment: @xHocquet sure, by using a couple of compositing steps you can clip the triangle shape, then fill it in with the gradient. I added a demo for convenience :) (you could cache the triangle with the gradient on a separate canvas and just draw a clipped version of it back onto the main canvas).

Comment: @xHocquet ok, I added a demo code for cached image approach, as I would recommend this for performance reasons (I don't set sizes of the canvas as the default is 300x150, perfect for the demo, but in real life code you need to set those as well as using none-self-closed canvas tag - I just get lazy with writing those n times .) ).

Answer (score 1):

You can use native html canvas by making your shapes (eg triangle) into a clipping regions.

This means any fills you do subsequently will not draw outside your triangle.

**All you have to do is:**

- Draw you triangle
- Make it a clipping region
- Draw a green rectangle over the top 1/3 of your triangle. **Don't worry**...the rectangle will be clipped to appear only where it is inside the triangle.
- Draw a blue rectangle over the middle 1/3 of your triangle
- Draw a red rectangle over the bottom 1/3 of your triangle

**Here's example code and a demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var points=[];
points.push({x:100,y:50});
points.push({x:150,y:150});
points.push({x:50,y:150});
points.push({x:100,y:50});

drawPoints(points);

function drawPoints(pts){
  var minY= 100000;
  var maxY=-100000;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i=0;i<pts.length;i++){
    var p=pts[i];
    if(i==0){
      ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
    }else{
      ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y);
    }
    if(p.y<minY){minY=p.y;}
    if(p.y>maxY){maxY=p.y;}
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.clip();

  var height=maxY-minY;
  ctx.fillStyle='green';
  ctx.fillRect(0,minY,cw,minY,height/3);
  ctx.fillStyle='blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0,minY+height/3,cw,height/3);
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.fillRect(0,minY+height*2/3,cw,height/3);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Yo! This answer is perfect. Thanks a lot, didn't know about the masks. Could you guide me in the direction of how to calculate the percentages based on an array or object of numbers. Calculate the total, get ratios, iterate through ratios and generate rectangle * ratio of 100% height?

Comment: You're welcome! **Here's how to calculate heights:** (1) Given `var data=[3,4,6];` calculate the total of data: `var total=0; for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){total+=data[i];}` (2) Calculate the `var height` (same as in my answer), (3) Calculate each rect height based on the percentage of each datum to the total height: `var heights=[]; for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){heights[i]=data[i]/total*height;}` Good luck with your project!